# Why am i getting 'Unable to get property 'pAmt' of undefined or null reference'

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

My  Jquery Datatables is populated without problems,i am using:-

- Datatables version 1.10.12 and
- Jquery version 1.11.1
- List item

But after editing and saving ,i am getting  "Unable to get property 'pAmt' of undefined or null reference".Below is the function which is called after clicking save button

```
function onDealPaymentChange(dealPmtId) {
            var theForm = document.getElementById("updateDealPmtForm" + dealPmtId);
            var amount = trim(theForm.pAmt.value, "both");
            var invDate = theForm.pInvDate.value;
            var recvDate = theForm.pRecDate.value;

            if (isNaN(amount) || amount == "") {
                alert("Invalid payment amount.")
            } else if (!isDate(invDate, "Invoice")) {
                //alert("Invalid invoice date");
            } else if (recvDate != "" && !isDate(recvDate, "Received")) {
                //alert("Invalid Received Date");
            } else {
                theForm.submit();
            }
    }
```

Comment: use alert, console.log or debugger to check if you are getting a valid object "theForm".

Answer (score 2):

The culprit would be this line:

```
var amount = trim(theForm.pAmt.value, "both");
```

At the time where this function is executed, `theForm` is either null or undefined. If you were to comment out the line mentioned, I would expect that the next error to occur would mention something about `Unable to get property 'pInvDate' of undefined or null reference.`

Throw a `console.log(theForm);` statement just above the `var amount = ...;` line, it should show you that `theForm` is undefined or null at the browser console.

Comment: Thank you  Isabellle!!The form was not defined previously,...It is  defined now.But now i am getting the value of  var amount = trim(theForm.pAmt.value, "both"); but  i am not able to get the value of  var invDate = theForm.pInvDate.value;So it  says  Unable to get property 'pInvDate' of undefined or null reference.

Comment: Frank, it should not be any different... since `pInvDate` is also on `theForm`. If it's not undefined for `pAmt` it should not be undefined for `pInvDate`.

Comment: That what i was thinking.......i am not sure what is  wrong.Since the the Form object now is defined and amount is  defined as well except pInvDate